# Resizing view using onTouchListener

Tags: android, resize, ontouchlistener

Hi I am creating an application that would simply resize a view when I start dragging a button designated for resizing.

Layout to be resized is declared as: `resizeAbleLayout` and the button for dragging to resize that layout is declared as: `btnResize`

I have been able to resize the view but when I finished resizing the view, and start to resize it again it does not start to resize from the size that I left it.

My question is that how would I be able to save the last resized position of the view and smoothly resize it without shinking suddenly? :D

This is my code used for btnResize:

```
  btnResize.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x=(int)event.getX();
            int y=(int)event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        resizeAbleLayout.getLayoutParams().width = x;
                        resizeAbleLayout.getLayoutParams().height = y;
                        resizeAbleLayout.requestLayout();
                        break;
                }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: What do you mean by suddenly shrink ?

Comment: @KhalidTaha Sorry I should edit that. I mean that it does not start from the same size that I resized it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `+=` or `-=` not to use `=`:

```
switch (event.getAction()){
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     resizeAbleLayout.getLayoutParams().width += x/Math.abs(x);
     resizeAbleLayout.getLayoutParams().height += y/Math.abs(y);
     resizeAbleLayout.requestLayout();
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very late to answer but I was have similar problem and solve it with set `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` for parent of resizable view. It seems there is a bug in android with `rtl` direction in this case. Hope it help.