# cropping a Bitmap based on overlay in Android - Camera API 2

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-bitmap, android-camera2

I am using Camera api to capture ID cards pictures, I have an over lay as shown in the image bellow. I want to crop the image in the box. could you suggest on how exactly it should be done. I have written down what I have tried and the results it gives me.

This is the screenshot of the id i want to capture..

[image]

Output.

[image]

white rectangular box is a photo frame which is right in the centre in a Relative layout

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/photo_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="212dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_photo_frame"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/double_padding"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

How do I calculate this frame to cut the image

this is what I have to cut the image which needs modification but not sure what is the way forward

```
       public Bitmap cutImage(final Bitmap srcBmp, final int pixepWidth, final int pixelsHeight, float widthRatio) {
//        Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 20, 20, pixepWidth, pixelsHeight);
//        return croppedBitmap;
        Bitmap dstBmp;
        if (srcBmp.getWidth() >= srcBmp.getHeight()){

            dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    srcBmp,
                    srcBmp.getWidth()/2 - srcBmp.getHeight()/2,
                    0,
                    srcBmp.getHeight(),
                    srcBmp.getHeight()
            );

        }else{

            dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    srcBmp,
                    0,
                    srcBmp.getHeight()/2 - srcBmp.getWidth()/2,
                    srcBmp.getWidth(),
                    srcBmp.getWidth()
            );
        }

        return dstBmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Resizing view using onTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902248/resizing-view-using-ontouchlistener)

You apply some kind of touchListener to the overlay view for resizing and moving the overlay. ImageButton seems to work, so I use ImageButton with a frame.xml to draw a border.

Then you apply the global coordinates of the overlay (x, y, width, height) against the coordinates of the bitmap (x, y, width, height).

The overlay x and the overlay y can’t be less than 0, and the overlay x + the overlay width cannot be greater than the bitmap width.

To perform the crop, use Bitmap.createBitmap():

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

[How to crop Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852127/how-to-crop-bitmap)